# Does the foursquare Push (Realtime) API Retry to Send on Failed POST?

Tags: api, push, real-time, foursquare

Documentation on the Real-Time API is fairly sparse on the mechanisms behind the push notifications. Does the Foursquare API retry to POST a notification (checkin) if the receiving endpoint is unresponsive at the time?  For example, here is Facebook's retry policy:

"If a change notification to your server fails, Facebook will retry again immediately, then a few times more, with decreasing frequency, over the next 24 hours."

Does foursquare have anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foursquare does not retry push requests at this time. You can (albeit inefficiently) call /users/self/checkins?afterTimestamp=XXXX for each user with their access token to retrieve their recent check-ins in the event you believe you've missed check-ins.